# Is it practically possible to detect big and solid amount of steel on the ground at long distances? (e.g. vehicles)

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it practically possible to detect big and solid amounts of steel on the ground at long distances? (e.g. vehicles on line of sight)
Metal detectors do it but at short distances and suffer of parasitic detections from minerals in the soil and etc.
Radars detect it well but can't distinguish from other non metal but big objects.

Comment: what is the physics question?

Comment: does the current state of physics allow the humankind to detect big and solid bodies of metal at long distances? is it physically possible?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, as follows.

There is a sensitive device called a *magnetometer* which detects tiny variations in the strength of the earth's magnetic field. Big chunks of steel perturb that field, and so you can put a magnetometer in an airplane, fly over the ocean, and find submerged submarines with it. If the sub is made of, say, copper instead of steel, the magnetometer can't "see" it.

Tow one across the bottom of the ocean and you can find sunken ships.

Fly it over a mountain range and you can find deposits of iron ore underground.

A type of magnetometer is cut into the pavement at automatic traffic lights to sense the presence of cars waiting for the light to change.